# Update one field of specific records using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 TextBoxes for enter 2 id and a TextBox for enter amount.I want to add this amount to amount in my table with first id,and minus to amount in my table with second id.
This is my code:

```
int money = Int16.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        List<account> q_to = (from p in context.accounts where p.id.ToString() == textBox2.Text select p).ToList();
        foreach (account p in q_to)
        {
            p.amount = p.amount + money;
        }


        List<account> q_from = (from p in context.accounts where p.id.ToString() == textBox1.Text select p).ToList();
        foreach (account p in q_from)
        {
            if (p.amount < money)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Account balance is not enough");
            }
            p.amount = p.amount - money;
        }
```

But just update first row.
What should i do?

Comment: If you know the row you want to update you can perform a `SELECT` query to select that row from the database and the use a `For each row in datatable` type loop to update it (Only 1 row = only 1 update). Likewise, give the row some sort of an ID that is unique (Like an AutoNumber), and update it by that unique field. What `DBMS` are you using?

Comment: Can you show the code where you bind the updated data back to your gridview?

Comment: try
            {
                context.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                // Provide for exceptions.
            } @sr28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should create this code if you want to save changes in database:

```
 try
        {
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            // Provide for exceptions.
        }
```

And if you want to see updates on your database,you should refresh the form :

```
this.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an `else` to go with the `if` in the second loop. Otherwise the `money` is always subtracted.

Also you should only add the `money` to the first account if it was OK to subtract it from the 2nd account. Right now you are adding it always. I would not like to be the one in charge of this 'bank'....

Comment: It appears I misunderstood the question. But this seems like it's the right method, you're currently updating the value even if there isn't enough money - Just a logic error, nothing actually wrong with the code itself.

Comment: yes,you are right.but my problem is just first row become update.when i debbug it ,other rows become update but in gridview show the first row. @David

Comment: I made an edit to my answer, not related to your 'updating' problem, just to make the business logic still better.

Answer (score 0):

Might be slightly better performance-wise to simply get 1 big list for both account types and then do a subtraction or addition depending on the account type:

```
int money = Int16.Parse(textBox3.Text);

List<account> q_accounts = (from p in context.accounts 
                            where p.id.ToString() == textBox2.Text ||
                                  p.id.ToString() == textBox1.Text
                            select p).ToList();

foreach (account p in q_accounts)
{
    if (p.id.ToString() == textBox2.Text)
    {
        p.amount = p.amount + money;
    }
    else
    {
        if (p.amount < money)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Account balance is not enough");
        }
        else
        {
            p.amount = p.amount - money;
        }
    }
}
```

This will stop you from going over the accounts list twice to pull out both account types.

Comment: like before.if one of the ids that I entered in textbox was 1 ,first row became update.else other rows didn;t update @sr28

Comment: my problem is just first row become update.when i debbug it ,other rows become update but in gridview show the first row. @sr28

Comment: @sara - so just to be clear, are you saying that you are putting multiple ids into you textbox or just 1? If just 1, are you saying that if the id is anything other than the first row it doesn't update?

Comment: I can save changes in my database.But this change only in the form shown in the first row @sr28

Comment: @sara - what exactly is 'context'?